# What should go in the model and what should go in the controller?

Tags: javascript, separation-of-concerns

First I'm doing this in NoSQL & node.js. I assume that shouldn't effect the question but it will help understand my example.

I have a model for a page and a tag that look something like this:

```
var Page = app.ormDb.define('pages', {
    uuid            : { type: String, index: true, length: 40, default: function () { return uuid.v4(); } },
    title           : { type: String, index: true, length: 255 },
    url             : { type: String, index: true, length: 255 },
    summary_mu      : { type: String, length: 1024 },
    summary_html    : { type: String },
    summary_hist    : { type: JSON, default: function() { rerutn { items : [] }; } },
    sections        : { type: JSON, default: function() { rerutn { items : [] }; } },
    tags            : { type: JSON, default: function() { rerutn { items : [] }; } },
    date            : { type: Date, default: function() { return new Date(); } },
    updated         : { type: Date, default: function() { return new Date(); } }
});

var Tag = app.ormDb.define('tags', {
    uuid        : { type: String, index: true, length: 40, default: function () { return uuid.v4(); } },
    name        : { type: String, index: true, length: 255 },
    url         : { type: String, index: true, length: 255 },
    desc        : { type: String, length: 1024 },
    date        : { type: Date, default: function() { return new Date(); } },
    updated     : { type: Date, default: function() { return new Date(); } }
});
```

So now I have some data maintenance issues, for example when I add a tag to a page I need to make sure there is a tag entry. To this end I've created a method on the model.

```
// Add a tag to a page
//   tag .. The tag to add
Page.prototype.addTag(tag, done) {
    var _this = this;
    if (_this.tags == null) {
        _this.tags = { items:[] };
    }

    var index = _this.tags.items.indexOf(tag);
    if (index == -1) {
        _this.tags.items.push(tag);
    }

    async.waterfall([
        function (cb) {
            app.models.tag.count({'name': tag}, cb);
        },
        function (count, cb) {
            if (count == 0) {
                app.models.tag.create({
                    name : tag,
                }, function (err, newTag) {
                    return cb(err, tag);
                });
            } else {
                return cb(null, tag);
            }
        }
    ], function (err, items) {
        done(err, items);
    });
}
```

In the controller I have code that verifies the user input, loads the current page, calls the Page method above to add the tag, and finally saving the updated page. Note, in the method above I'm checking the Tag collection for the existence of the tag, and creating it if needed.

Is this correct, or should the Page method's logic be moved to the controller and the model *only* deal with the one model and not others?

My reasoning is that I would never add a tag to a page without checking/creating the tag in the Tag collection.

Comment: you are using client side-mvc right?

Comment: @imsiso no, this is server side. A RESTful API. The view is basically the returned JSON from the API call.

Comment: you know the mvc is the structure and frameworks tried to apply its parts. And different frameworks have different definition for each parts. ie(some of them just have views others have views + layouts and some others have view + view-on-view).let me read your question again.

Comment: I couldn't read your question carefully and I should leave now but. As I had understand about mvc:(its relates to how your framework is (or your base code is powerful)) you should do things on controller very skinny I mean if you want an HTML table created with array you should give it to view helper or something. when you want to work with data sources you should be aware of table structure (I know you know) and you can pass the validations to something out of controller (another class that does that for controller)(maybe the model or something that model uses that). its something formal